# Camera model is not supported with installed version of Camera Raw

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a Canon EOS 550D and I am having a problem with opening my RAW photo file in Photoshop. The program signals that the RAW file is not compatible with the installed version of Camera Raw due to my camera model.

Is it the camera itself or would I have to adjust something in the program?

Comment: What version of Photoshop do you have?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is updating your installed version of Camera Raw through *Adobe Updater*, which you will find sitting in your systray already, prompting you to upgrade, or in your Programs.

Adobe will automatically try and give you the latest version of Camera Raw, which includes support for all recent camera models.

If that doesn't work, you can download it from Adobe's [Update site](http://www.adobe.com/downloads/updates/). See here for a list of Camera Raw updates:

- [Windows](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Windows)
- [Mac](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Mac)